# Is the law of the lever equation the same in classical physics as in relativity ? Why?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, energy, gravity

In classical mechanics the balancing lever equation (law of the lever) is

$$M_1 a = M_2 b$$

Where $M_1$ is the mass at a distance $a$ from the fulcrum and $M_2$ is the mass at a distance $b$ from the fulcrum.

Is this the same as in other physics such as special or general relativity ?

I considered lenght contraction and time dilation if things are moving but I think those factors cancel out because they appear equally on both sides ?

Like

$$M_1 a \gamma = M_2 b \gamma$$

is basically the same, and places the balancing point at the same place.

I think even a changing gravitational field makes no difference if it changes equal at both sides.

Wait if the lenght is relative and the equation hold does it still mean the fulcrum is at the same place ??

I am a bit confused.

But I think it must hold and it is independant of the observer.

Am I correct ? Why ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some right ideas. But it might be a little more complicated than you are thinking. Or maybe a little simpler.

If you are in the rest frame of a lever, you can use the classical law to figure out what mass will balance what.

If you run by the lever at relativistic speed, the lever will still balance. But you will see it as being in a moving frame.

It will be forshortened in the direction of travel. If the lever is at an angle like a seesaw with one end on the ground, the perpendicular components of distance are not contracted. You will see the end at the same height as in the rest frame. So you will see it at a steeper angle.